# Regex match paramaters in array of arrays

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Specifically I need it to do a find & replace in VSCode search.

What I have tried: `buildFromArray\(\[(\s*(\[.*\]),?\s*)*`

I can't seem to get the correct regex though. I have also tried using `buildFromArray` as a lookbehind in the regex like this: `(?<=buildFromArray\(\[\s*)(?:(\[.*\]),?\n\s*)*`

This works in regexr.com but vscode gives me this error:

> lookbehind assertion is not fixed length

I need to match these tests:

```
buildFromArray([
      [1, 2, -1, -2],
      [3, 4, true, "test"],
      [2, 45, -3, -4],
])
```

```
buildFromArray([['test']], {useArrayArithmetic: true})
```

And produce the capture groups for the parameters like so:

`[1, 2, -1, -2]`

`[3, 4, true, "test"]`

`[2, 45, -3, -4]`

And:

`['test']`

Comment: Where are you using the regex? It is definitely not the search and replace feature (neither in-document, nor the "magnifying glass" file search). Is it syntax highlighting?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is the global search in vscode, magnifying glass search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised to see the VSCode is so primitive regarding Regex (I thought it used .Net Regex, but apparently not - .Net could capture repeating groups and supports look behind with var length).

So I think your best option is to repeat the pattern (and make the second and third groups optional, like this:

```
buildFromArray\(\[\s*(\[[^\]]+\])(?:,\s*(\[[^\]]+\]))?(?:,\s*(\[[^\]]+\]))?
```

As you can see, `(?:,\s*(\[[^\]]+\]))?` is simply repeated. It creates three groups. However, in your second test, group1 and group2 will be empty.

Comment: Thanks. This got me in the right direction.

I had to use return char too like so:

`buildFromArray\(\[[\s\r]*(\[[^\]]+\])(?:,\s*(\[[^\]]+\]))?(?:,\s*(\[[^\]]+\]))?`

Comment: Hmm, `\r` should be part of white space `\s` , but as long as it works, it's fine.